# Exporting logs from Snort to Syslog-ng to Redis

Tags: redis, snort, syslog-ng

I am using Snort 2.9.3 and would like to export the logs to Syslog-ng, and then from syslog-ng to a Redis database.
I found a plugin: syslog-ng-mod-redis
However, where would I include this?

How can I confirm that the logs produced by Snort can be read by syslog-ng?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

If you install a plugin, it will be loaded automatically. You can check it with the following command:

syslog-ng -V

On Ubuntu syslog-ng is confined by AppArmor. Check your security logs, and if you see that access was denied, add a rule to AppArmor to be able to read Snort logs.